# Firebase Web Push background message is never displayed

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase web push notification in our web application.

The message send from the FCM is never displayed when the application is not active or open. No errors generated.

Front End Code:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.6.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script>
        MsgElem = document.getElementById("msg")
        TokenElem = document.getElementById("token")
        NotisElem = document.getElementById("notis")
        ErrElem = document.getElementById("err")
        // Initialize Firebase
        // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
        var config = {
            apiKey: "<apikey>",
            authDomain: "<app>.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
            storageBucket: "<app>.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "<id>",
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);

        const messaging = firebase.messaging();
        messaging
            .requestPermission()
            .then(function () {
                MsgElem.innerHTML = "Notification permission granted." 
                console.log("Notification permission granted.");

                // get the token in the form of promise
                return messaging.getToken()
            })
            .then(function(token) {
                TokenElem.innerHTML = "token is : " + token
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                ErrElem.innerHTML =  ErrElem.innerHTML + "; " + err
                console.log("Unable to get permission to notify.", err);
            });

        messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
            console.log("Message received. ", payload);
            NotisElem.innerHTML = NotisElem.innerHTML + JSON.stringify(payload) 
        });
    </script>
```

firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
    importScripts ('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.6.0/firebase-app.js');

    importScripts ('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.6.0/firebase-messaging.js');

    firebase.initializeApp ({'messagingSenderId': 'id'});

    const messaging = firebase.messaging();

    messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler (function(payload) {

    console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);

     const data = payload.data;
     const notificationTitle = data.title;
     const notificationOptions = {
body: data.body
     };

      return self.registration.showNotification (notificationTitle,  notificationOptions);
    });
```

FCM Request:

```
 {
      "to":"ids",
      "data":{
      "body":"clicktoaction",
      "title":"Simplext Notification"
      }
    }
```

The event messaging.onMessage (function(payload) is always called irrespective of the application is in fore ground or in background.

I tried changing the FCM Request from "data" to  "notification". It is still the same.

I am using Chrome v 70.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found that the firebase client app should be under https for the serviceworker to work.